# Create UINavigationBar Programmatically

Tags: ios, uiview, uinavigationbar

How come this code is not producing a UINavigationBar on my UIView?

```
//create the view
UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] init];
view.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

//everything for tabbar
UINavigationBar *navBar = [[UINavigationBar alloc] init];

//add the components to the view
[view addSubview: navBar];

//show the view
self.view = view;
```

I see the white view but no NavBar. Any help? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `view.frame = CGRectMake(x, y, w, h); navBar.frame = view.bounds;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the frame of navigation bar and add it as a subview of the view for it to be seen.Set a frame for any view to be positioned in its super view's coordinate system.

```
[navBar setFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,CGRectGetWidth(view.frame),44)];
[self.view addSubview:navBar];
```

Also its a navigation bar, I do not know what tab bar you are willing to see from this code you posted.

Comment: Oops. I get NavBars and TabBars mixed up.

Comment: `[self.view addSubview:navBar];` doesn't work in my case. I need to add it to `UIView *view` so I need to use `[view addSubview:navBar];`

Comment: Did you set the frame of view too? Because I dont see its frame was set up there. Set the view's frame to something you want or equal to screen bounds.

Comment: UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] init];  set a frame of this view you just created like you set it for navBar.